# statsmodels mlemodel.MLEResults 'MLEResults' object has no attribute 'get_smoothed_decomposition'

Tags: statsmodels

I create a subclass sm.tsa.statespace.MLEModel. I want the trend component of the series.

```
class LocalLinearTrend(sm.tsa.statespace.MLEModel):
    ...

model = LocalLinearTrend(endog=NP1['LnKSI']) 

result = model.fit(method='lbfgs', maxiter=50) 

Decomp = result.get_smoothed_decomposition()
```

Produces error: AttributeError: 'MLEResults' object has no attribute 'get_smoothed_decomposition'

But the documentation for MLEresults shows:
get_smoothed_decomposition([...])
Decompose smoothed output into contributions from observations

How to get the trend component from the fitted model?

Thanks for any guidance or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The `get_smoothed_decomposition` method was only recently added and has not been in an official release yet. It will be in the next release (v0.14).

However, if you're simply looking for the smoothed estimate of one of the elements of the state vector, you can use `result.states.smoothed`, which is a Pandas DataFrame.

Comment: Hi @cfulton,

Thanks for reformating my code (still learning stackoverflow). I see result.states.smoothed. But I also see result.smoothed_state with many other useful attributes such as smoothed_state_cov. Which attribute is better for state vectors?

Comment: `result.states.smoothed` gives the same information as `result.smoothed_state`, but in a slightly nicer form (Pandas DataFrame versus transposed Numpy array).

Comment: If you do need the smoothed covariances, then yes, you would need to use `result.smoothed_state_cov` directly.

Comment: Thanks. I just saw the same explanation in your Github post from 2019. I like to use Numpy arrays.

Comment: What is the MLEResult property to show or calculate the Standard Residual for 'y'?  As plot_diagnostics chart shows.